# Access localhost on port 81 from different computer

Tags: iis

I'm a developer and web set up is not my strong suit.

I'm trying to run two different apps on my local computer using IIS.

I hosted one of them on port 80 and the other one on port 81.

I also made a few changes in my hosts file to be able to access apps by different adress:

- 127.0.0.1 mes.operator (this one is set up on port 81)
- 127.0.0.1 mes.manager (this one is set up on port 80)

Now I can access the app running on port 80 by adresses:
mes.manager or localhost or from another computer by ip adress of computer that is hosting the app.

But the other app is only available on adress:
mes.manager:81

I thought this will also be available on localhost:81 but it is not. What am I missing ?

The main goal is to be able to access mes.manager from another computer but if I can't even do that by localhost:81 than the ip-of-localComputer:81 also wont work.

Comment: "than the ip-of-localComputer:81 also wont work." have you actually tested this, or are you just assuming?  Have you se the site to anwer on any IP on that port?  If you head into the IIS Manager, click the port 81 site and click "browse <site> on *.:81", what happens?  Can you post a screen shot (or just transpose it into text) of the site's current Bindings (from IIS Manager)?

Comment: Just realized, you don't' have enough rep to post a picture. If you want to, just upload it to Imgur.com or alike, and edit a link to it into your question.  Someone with more rep will come along and convert it to an in-line picture for you. :)

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 thanks to what you wrote I actually saw what I was missing :P  In IIS I had configured only the binding for mes.operator and mes.manager. For this to work I has to add *.:81 binding. Working now! Thanks for the help :) Also accessible from another computer (firewall turned off for now for testing purposes.)

Comment: Excellent, good to hear!  I wrote up an answer to make it all official-like. ;)

Comment: You cannot connect to a remote address if you connect to localhost, localhost unless configured to another address, is configured to 127.0.0.1 which is the physical machine you are using.  You create create localhost2 if you want, but localhost if you changed it to another address other then 127.0.0.1, will always point to the physical machine your using.  What currently works is what is suppose to work per your current configurations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Head into the IIS Manager, click the port 81 site check the site's current Bindings to ensure it's bound on the right port, to all addresses that you want it to answer on.

Example screenshot of editing the bindings:

[image]